# What's the format of po file in poedit?

Tags: wordpress, poedit

I want to add the words to the .po file and translate them to fa language , but I don't know what's the format of writing it ! 
for example :

```
#: ????
msgid "En sentences"
msgstr "fa sentences"
```

Can anybody explain?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html

Answer (score 0):

PO files are the files which contain the actual translations. Each language will have its own PO file.
MO files are binary data files that contains object data referenced by a program and created from PO files.
So Po files should be converted to Mo files. You cant do this conversion manually. Use [Poedit](https://poedit.net/wordpress) Gettext Translations Editor to create Po and Mo translation files.

See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227822/what-is-the-difference-between-po-mo-and-pot-files-in-wordpress-localization

Comment: Thanks from your guidance , but I think we can add words to .po file with notepad++ !

Comment: .po files must be converted to .mo binary files. without .mo binary files translation not works properly. and note that you can not edit .mo files manullay.

Comment: Ok , that's true ! Now , How to convert my .po file to .mo binary files ?

Answer (score 0):

open .po file with poedit https://www.poedit.net/

file menu -> compile to MO menu

you can get .mo file